# Saldo en tiempo real en una consulta dependiendo de una columna

Tags: mysql

Para que quede claro, esto es en una consula MySQL

Necesito resolver lo siguiente:
En la columna “A” tengo una cadena de caracteres, en la “B” y en la “C” tengo valores numéricos. La columna “D” tiene que reflejar el cálculo de “B” menos “C” siempre y cuando “A” tenga el mismo valor. A continuación un ejemplo:

```
A       B        C       D
Data1   10        2       8
Data1             2       6
Data2   50        2      48
Data2            10      38
```

En la consulta real se utiliza UNION, las columnas de referencia son las siguientes:

A=sim_items_djai_declaacancelar

B=sim_items_djai_cantidaddec

C=sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec

```
(SELECT
cmn_lst_clientes._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_desc,
cmn_lst_clientes_un._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_un_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar AS sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_caratula._oficializacion AS sim_caratula_oficializacion,
opr_djai_estado._fb AS opr_djai_estado_fb,
opr_djai_estado._fv AS opr_djai_estado_fv,
sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar AS sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar,
opr_lst_djai_estados._descesAR as opr_lst_djai_estados_desc,
sim_items_djai._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_cantidaddec,
sim_lst_um._descesAR as sim_lst_um_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn as sim_items_djai_decla_destsimn,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion AS sim_items_djai_decla_oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla._item as sim_items_djai_decla_item,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec,
(sim_items_djai._cantidaddec - sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec) as _varSaldo2d
FROM
sim_items AS sim_items_djai_decla USE INDEX (_declaacancelar)
INNER JOIN sim_caratula USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = sim_caratula._destsimn AND sim_caratula._destsim = 'SIMI'
INNER JOIN opr_djai_estado USE INDEX (_destsimnitem) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = opr_djai_estado._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar = opr_djai_estado._item
INNER JOIN opr_lst_djai_estados USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._estado = opr_lst_djai_estados._id
LEFT JOIN sim_items AS sim_items_djai USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._destsimn = sim_items_djai._destsimn AND opr_djai_estado._oficializacion = sim_items_djai._oficializacion AND opr_djai_estado._item = sim_items_djai._item
INNER JOIN sim_lst_um USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai._unidaddec = sim_lst_um._id
INNER JOIN opr_djai USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._destsimn = opr_djai._destsimn AND opr_djai_estado._oficializacion = opr_djai._oficializacion
INNER JOIN cmn_lst_clientes USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes._id
INNER JOIN cmn_lst_clientes_un USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes_un._cliente AND opr_djai._un = cmn_lst_clientes_un._un
WHERE
(sim_caratula._oficializacion >= '2015-12-22'
and sim_caratula._oficializacion <= '2016-04-29')
and opr_djai._cliente = '61'
GROUP BY
sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn)
UNION
(SELECT
cmn_lst_clientes._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_desc,
cmn_lst_clientes_un._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_un_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn AS sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion AS sim_caratula_oficializacion,
opr_djai_estado._fb AS opr_djai_estado_fb,
opr_djai_estado._fv AS opr_djai_estado_fv,
sim_items_djai_decla._item AS sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar,
opr_lst_djai_estados._descesAR as opr_lst_djai_estados_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_cantidaddec,
sim_lst_um._descesAR as sim_lst_um_desc,
'' as sim_items_djai_decla_destsimn,
null AS sim_items_djai_decla_oficializacion,
'' as sim_items_djai_decla_item,
0 as sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as _varSaldo2d
FROM
sim_items AS sim_items_djai_decla USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
LEFT JOIN sim_caratula USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = sim_caratula._destsimn AND sim_caratula._destsim = 'SIMI'
LEFT JOIN sim_items ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = sim_items._declaacancelar AND sim_items_djai_decla._item = sim_items._itemacancelar
LEFT JOIN opr_djai ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = opr_djai._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion = opr_djai._oficializacion
LEFT JOIN cmn_lst_clientes ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes._id
LEFT JOIN cmn_lst_clientes_un ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes_un._cliente AND opr_djai._un = cmn_lst_clientes_un._un
LEFT JOIN opr_djai_estado ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = opr_djai_estado._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion = opr_djai_estado._oficializacion AND sim_items_djai_decla._item = opr_djai_estado._item
LEFT JOIN opr_lst_djai_estados ON opr_djai_estado._estado = opr_lst_djai_estados._id
LEFT JOIN sim_lst_um ON sim_items_djai_decla._unidaddec = sim_lst_um._id
WHERE
ISNULL(sim_items._declaacancelar)
AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion >= '2015-12-22'
AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion <= '2016-04-29'
and opr_djai._cliente = '61'
GROUP BY
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla._item)
ORDER BY
sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_caratula_oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar
```

Comment: ¿Esto lo quieres hacer con una consulta?¿O lo quieres hacer dentro de otro lenguaje (p.e.: PHP) para mostrar los resultados?

Comment: Hola, si posteas el codigo de lo que intentaste estaria bien, no es muy claro lo que preguntas.

Comment: La idea es hacerlo en un query en MySQL, no usar PHP u otro lenguaje.

Comment: SELECT
a,
b,
c,
b - c as d <- acá la complejidad, si el registro en a = registro en columna a anterior.

en el caso que el registro sea el primero y no exista uno anterior el valor de anterior debería ser igual al del primer registro.

Comment: No sería exactamente b-c as d, porque la última columna es b-c si es la primera, d_anterior-c a partir de ahí

Comment: Se que es confuso, por eso la idea de crear la tabla que representa lo que necesito.  Cada vez q la columna A cambia el saldo inicial debería también cambiar, en este ejemplo sería la columna B, la D es la dinámica.  Mientras la columna A sea igual va restando, si cambia toma como saldo inicial la B

Comment: Aún faltan mucha información: ¿cómo sabes el orden?¿de donde vienen los datos (de otras tablas o es todo en una tabla solo)?¿se puede usar una vista?¿Qué campo es la clave? O directamente, ¿tienes una clave?

Comment: Alvaro, gracias por tu tiempo.  La consulta es mucho más compleja, tiene hasta un UNION de dos condiciones para cuando tiene algunos registros en una tabla y para cuando no, los ordena y muestra.  Imaginemos sólo una tabla con los campos A, B y C.  D es el resultado de la resta de B - C siempre y cuando A sea el mismo, en caso de ser el primer registro es el más complejo ya q no tiene con quien comparar anteriormente a si mismo por lo que debería ser igual (me refiero a una variable)

Comment: Por favor, detalla qué hace la consulta que has añadido en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo reconozco, voy a hacer un poco de trampa y asumir un dato que no aparece en la pregunta: la tabla tiene una clave primaria de tipo numérico. De este modo la estructura de la tabla sería (al menos) algo como esto:

- id: clave primaria de tipo `int`.
- nombre: tipo varchar(50) con un `index`.
- total: tipo `int`, puede contener el valor `null`.
- menos: tipo `int` y no puede ser `null`.

Y el contenido de la tabla va a ser el siguiente:

```
id     nombre       total      menos
----   ----------   --------   --------
1      Data1        10         2
2      Data1        10         2
3      Data2        50         2
4      Data2        50         10
```

Así lo que querrías hacer es lo siguiente en la consulta:

- Para el primer campo, seleccionar el nombre, sin más.
- Lo mismo para el segundo campo: simplemente seleccionar el total.
- El tercer campo es un poco más complicado:

  - Por un lado necesitamos el total (que sería <strike>el valor más alto para ese nombre</strike> el total de esa columna)
  - Por otro lado necesitamos la resta de todo lo que se haya calculado hasta ahora (un `SUM` de todos los valores anteriores para este nombre)

  una vez se tengan esas dos subconsultas, se resta la una a la otra.

Sé que puede no ser la manera más eficiente, pero obtienes el resultado que esperas y  no es una consulta excesivamente grande.

El código de la consulta se vería así:

```
SELECT a.nombre, 
       a.total, 
       a.menos, 
       a.total - (SELECT SUM(b.menos) FROM `test` b WHERE b.id <= a.id AND b.nombre = a.nombre) AS resta
FROM   `test` a 
ORDER  BY a.nombre ASC, a.total DESC
```

Cuando se ejecuta esa consulta, el resultado obtenido es el siquiente:

```
nombre       total      menos       resta
----------   --------   --------    -----
Data1        10         2           8
Data1        10         2           6
Data2        50         2           48
Data2        50         10          38
```

nombre es sim_items_djai_declaacancelar
total es sim_items_djai_cantidaddec
menos es sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec

```
(SELECT
cmn_lst_clientes._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_desc,
cmn_lst_clientes_un._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_un_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar AS sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_caratula._oficializacion AS sim_caratula_oficializacion,
opr_djai_estado._fb AS opr_djai_estado_fb,
opr_djai_estado._fv AS opr_djai_estado_fv,
sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar AS sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar,
opr_lst_djai_estados._descesAR as opr_lst_djai_estados_desc,
sim_items_djai._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_cantidaddec,
sim_lst_um._descesAR as sim_lst_um_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn as sim_items_djai_decla_destsimn,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion AS sim_items_djai_decla_oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla._item as sim_items_djai_decla_item,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec,
(sim_items_djai._cantidaddec - sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec) as _varSaldo2d
FROM
sim_items AS sim_items_djai_decla USE INDEX (_declaacancelar)
INNER JOIN sim_caratula USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = sim_caratula._destsimn AND sim_caratula._destsim = 'SIMI'
INNER JOIN opr_djai_estado USE INDEX (_destsimnitem) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = opr_djai_estado._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar = opr_djai_estado._item
INNER JOIN opr_lst_djai_estados USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._estado = opr_lst_djai_estados._id
LEFT JOIN sim_items AS sim_items_djai USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._destsimn = sim_items_djai._destsimn AND opr_djai_estado._oficializacion = sim_items_djai._oficializacion AND opr_djai_estado._item = sim_items_djai._item
INNER JOIN sim_lst_um USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai._unidaddec = sim_lst_um._id
INNER JOIN opr_djai USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._destsimn = opr_djai._destsimn AND opr_djai_estado._oficializacion = opr_djai._oficializacion
INNER JOIN cmn_lst_clientes USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes._id
INNER JOIN cmn_lst_clientes_un USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes_un._cliente AND opr_djai._un = cmn_lst_clientes_un._un
WHERE
(sim_caratula._oficializacion >= '2015-12-22'
and sim_caratula._oficializacion <= '2016-04-29')
and opr_djai._cliente = '61'
GROUP BY
sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn)
UNION
(SELECT
cmn_lst_clientes._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_desc,
cmn_lst_clientes_un._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_un_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn AS sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion AS sim_caratula_oficializacion,
opr_djai_estado._fb AS opr_djai_estado_fb,
opr_djai_estado._fv AS opr_djai_estado_fv,
sim_items_djai_decla._item AS sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar,
opr_lst_djai_estados._descesAR as opr_lst_djai_estados_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_cantidaddec,
sim_lst_um._descesAR as sim_lst_um_desc,
'' as sim_items_djai_decla_destsimn,
null AS sim_items_djai_decla_oficializacion,
'' as sim_items_djai_decla_item,
0 as sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as _varSaldo2d
FROM
sim_items AS sim_items_djai_decla USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
LEFT JOIN sim_caratula USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = sim_caratula._destsimn AND sim_caratula._destsim = 'SIMI'
LEFT JOIN sim_items ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = sim_items._declaacancelar AND sim_items_djai_decla._item = sim_items._itemacancelar
LEFT JOIN opr_djai ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = opr_djai._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion = opr_djai._oficializacion
LEFT JOIN cmn_lst_clientes ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes._id
LEFT JOIN cmn_lst_clientes_un ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes_un._cliente AND opr_djai._un = cmn_lst_clientes_un._un
LEFT JOIN opr_djai_estado ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = opr_djai_estado._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion = opr_djai_estado._oficializacion AND sim_items_djai_decla._item = opr_djai_estado._item
LEFT JOIN opr_lst_djai_estados ON opr_djai_estado._estado = opr_lst_djai_estados._id
LEFT JOIN sim_lst_um ON sim_items_djai_decla._unidaddec = sim_lst_um._id
WHERE
ISNULL(sim_items._declaacancelar)
AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion >= '2015-12-22'
AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion <= '2016-04-29'
and opr_djai._cliente = '61'
GROUP BY
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla._item)
ORDER BY
sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_caratula_oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar
```

Comment: Estamos muy cerca.  Para la columna total te cuento que siempre repite el mismo dato, en este ejemplo sería 10, 10 - 50, 50.  No los escribí para que sea más claro el ejemplo

Comment: Entonces es aún más sencillo: en lugar de tener que buscar el máximo de los totales, sólo tendrías que seleccionar el actual y te ahorrarías una subconsulta. Actualizando el código

Comment: Edito tu publicación para ver como aplico tu respuesta a mi consulta

Comment: Esa edición es demasiado grande. Deberías incluir ese código (o el código sin modificar) en la pregunta en lugar de en una respuesta. No me queda claro cómo aplicaste lo que puse en tu select

Comment: Lo agrego a la pregunta

Comment: Doy por válido este ejemplo ya que terminé resolvéndolo usando esta lógica

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar un TRIGGER, que se ejecute al momento de insertar o actualizar un registro en la tabla, te dejo un ejemplo de código que podría representar el escenario que comentas, el cual guarda el resultado de la sustracción en la columna 'calculated' previamente creada.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER calculate_column_insert BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.calculated = NEW.a - NEW.b;
  END;
|

CREATE TRIGGER calculate_column_update BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.calculated = NEW.a - NEW.b;
  END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

En caso quieras realizar el calculo desde el SELECT, podrías crear un alias para la columna calculada del modo siguiente.

```
SELECT A, B, (A + B) AS C FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: La idea es que el cálculo se haga en el momento de producir la consulta sin necesidad de estar actualizando un campo.  Estoy intentando hace unas cuantas horas intentar resolverlo con variables pero no logro hacer que funcione, en especial en el primer registro.

Para dar un ej simil JavaScript.
`
var prevRec = "";
if (prevRec == "") {
  prevRec = colA-Reg1;
}

if (prevRec <> colA-Reg1) {
  prevRec = colA-Reg1;
}`

Comment: Esto tendría siempre la columna actualizada, un TRIGGER se ejecuta de forma automática (no necesitas llamarlo para actualizar el campo), en este caso al insertar o actualizar un registro, eso como consecuencia tendría que cuando hagas un SELECT siempre tengas la columna con el valor actualizado.

Comment: Si quieres ejecutar el calculo al momento de hacer la consulta podrías simplemente colocarla en el SELECT, con SELECT a, b, (a+b) as c, FROM myTable

Comment: Joel, es lo q estoy intentando pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo, en espacial con el primer registro q no tiene uno anterior.  Si pudiera hacerlo en el código, por ej. PHP se resuelve con un par de variables y algunos IF, el tema es que necesito q lo resuelva MySQL pq me devuelve un json que se expresa en una planilla en javascript

Comment: También puedes usar algunos IF en MYSQL, pero debes recordar que el lenguaje es mas funcional, por lo que no puedes guardar valores temporales, al menos no en un solo query, en Functions y Procedures si, te dejo la traducción de un if en T-SQL, SELECT IF(A > 100, 100, A+B) AS C from MyTable;

Comment: Si lo que quieres hacer es leer el registro anterior, podrías, pero la consulta se complica demasiado, tendrías que tener una subconsulta que obtenga el anterior registro en función al indice y ese resultado usarlo como valor dentro del IF de forma que en función a esos valores mostrar un dato u otro, todo eso encerrarlo en un if mayor que valide que el registro anterior exista, Seguro que crear una función o un procedure y llamarlo desde el select no es una mejor opción?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas... supongo que deberia tener un id o algun incrementable que te diga cual es el orden de registro sino no sabrias cual viene primero, suponiendo esto: 
deberia verse asi:

id  A       B    C
1   data1   10  2
2   data1       2
3   data2   50  2
4   data2       10
5   data1       6
6   data2       7
 asi que la consulta si esta fuera una tabla. seria la siguiente:
**SELECT @data1:=0;

SELECT * ,IF(ISNULL(B),@data1:=(@data1-C),@data1:=(B-C)) AS D

FROM restas as res where A='data1';
**
lo hice para el data1, depende de ti como manejes lo demas, @data1, 'data1' en tu consulta puedes hacerla modificable y que te devuelva por cada nombre, o con un select group by o un distinct primero cargar los valores que entraran ahi, o el prepare, hay diferentes caminos que pueden ayudarte, lo otro mas sencillo seria un procedimiento almacenado.
y te devolveria lo siguiente
:
id  A       B    C   D
1   data1   10  2   8
2   data1       2   6
5   data1       6   0
11  data1       10  -10

el unico problema es que si hay mas restas te devolvera valores negativos.

espero te sirva.